# Can I search my Postman collection for a URL?

Tags: postman

I have a relative URL of an endpoint and I want to know if there is a Postman entry for it in my collection. Can I search the collection for this URL?

I tried pasting the URL and substrings of it into the "Filter" field without success.

EDIT: Since commenters said that this is unexpected behavior, here is a screenshot. Search returns no result even if I copy over the URL directly from the Postman entry.

[image]

Comment: Search works as expected, just make sure the collection tab is selected while filtering

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava I updated my question with a screenshot. It doesn't work for me unless I expect something else than you.

Comment: try api/branchOffice, I think the variable might be the issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding the substring into the `Find and Replace` should allow you to search for that value in the Workspace:

[image]

More info in the Postman Learning Center:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/navigating-postman/#find-and-replace